# Рандомный текст на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, случайные-числа, алгоритм

Как сделать рандомный текст на Python? Чтобы он выводил только 1 переменную из двух? Например, я беру две переменные с таким значением:

```
import random

role1 = "Мирный житель"
role2 = "Мафия"
role = randon.randomint(role1, role2)

print("Вы - " + role)

input("")
```

И мне нужно, чтобы при выводе текста выводилась ТОЛЬКО ОДНА ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ. Причем с каждого раза - разная, то role1, то role2, то снова role1.

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил. Я новичок в Python и прошу по подробнее отвечать.

Comment: Можете перефразировать вопрос? Очень не понятно, что значим «ТОЛЬКО ОДНА ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ» — у вас сейчас как раз выводится `role`. Если вы ищите функцию — то подойдет `random.choice`.

Comment: Уже не надо. Вы мне уже сказали правильную функцию :D

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: related: [Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2257441/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Случайный элемент из последовательности

[`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) использует криптографически-небезопасный PRNG в Питоне, поэтому если вы его используете в контексте, где не желательно, чтобы можно было угадать результат последовательных вызовов, например, при генерации паролей, то следует использовать CSPRNG такой как `random.SystemRandom()`, который использует [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom), который в свою очередь использует возможности, предоставляемые OS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

random_item = random.SystemRandom().choice(["Мирный житель", "Мафия"])
```

See also: [PEP 0506 -- Adding A Secrets Module To The Standard Library](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/). `secrets` модуль доступен с Python 3.6 -- его [`secrets.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice) метод это как раз [простой alias](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b428a1faed88f148ede131e3b86ab6227c6c3f0/Lib/secrets.py#L24) для `SystemRandom().choice`, показанного выше.

#### Каждый раз разная (неслучайная) строка

Чтобы при каждом запуске программы можно было печатать разные значения из заданной последовательности, можно создать бесконечный итератор, используя [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), который по кругу возвращает элементы из этой последовательности. Чтобы сохранить состояние итератора между запусками программы, чтобы каждый раз следующее значение возвращалось, можно использовать [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) для сериализации:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Print a different string on each run in a loop."""
import itertools
import pathlib
import pickle


# load items
path = pathlib.Path('it.pickle')
try:
    data = path.read_bytes()  # XXX no file locking, ignore concurrent issues
except FileNotFoundError:  # 1st run
    # create an infinite iterator that repeats the values
    it = itertools.cycle(iter({"Мирный житель", "Мафия"}))
else:
    # NOTE: it is insecure if you can't trust it.pickle's content
    it = pickle.loads(data)

# print next item
print(next(it))

# save items
path.write_bytes(pickle.dumps(it))  # XXX ignore data corruption issues
```

Чтобы избежать (маловероятного) повреждения файла (например, если питание вдруг пропадёт во время записи файла), можно использовать временный файл. See [Threadsafe and fault-tolerant file writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012813/4279).

Answer (score 3):

Из вопроса не очень понятно, что Вы хотите сделать. "Каждый раз разная" и "рандомная" (т.е. случайная) - это совершенно разные вещи. Поэтому попробуем сделать два варианта.

**Вариант 1. Случайная строка.**

```
import random

strings = ['String 1', 'String 2']
print(random.choice(strings))
```

**Вариант 2. Каждый раз разная строка.**

```
def next_string():
    strings = ('String 1', 'String 2')
    next_string.i = (next_string.i + 1) % len(strings)
    return strings[next_string.i]
next_string.i = -1

print(" ".join(next_string() for r in range(10)))
```

А вот так можно реализовать случай, когда при каждом следующем вызове программа выдаёт следующую строку:

```
def next_string():
    strings = ('String 1', 'String 2')
    if next_string.i < 0:
        try:
            with open("i.idx", 'r') as file:
                next_string.i = int(file.read())
        except Exception:
            pass
    next_string.i = (next_string.i + 1) % len(strings)
    with open("i.idx", 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(next_string.i))
    return strings[next_string.i]
next_string.i = -1

print(next_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно каждый раз рандомное значение, которое при этом бы ещё и не повторялось относительно предыдущих, перемешайте массив данных при помощи random.shuffle() и показывайте последовательно данные из него.

```py
import random

def rand_seq(seq):
    random.shuffle(seq_ := (seq if isinstance(seq, list) else list(seq)))
    return iter(seq_)
```

```py
>>> my_sequence = rand_seq(range(10))
>>> tuple(my_sequence)

(6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 9, 1, 2, 0)
```

```py
>>> my_sequence = rand_seq("синхрофазотрон")
>>> tuple(my_sequence)

('о', 'с', 'з', 'р', 'ф', 'о', 'х', 'н', 'о', 'т', 'а', 'р', 'и', 'н')
```