# Продолжение итерации, после прерывания программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день, задался вопросом, а как можно возобновить итерацию с генератора, если мы завершим процесс, а потом захотим его продолжить?

[Вот типа такого](http://pastebin.com/JQRxnZZB)

```
# ------------- file 1 -------------
import pickle
import itertools

def test(sym, L):
    return (''.join(q) for q in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(sym, repeat=i)for i in range(1, L + 1)))

h = test("1234567890",4)
f = open("test.pickle", "wb")

for i in range(1000):
    next(h)

print(next(h)) # 901
pickle.dump(h, f) # TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

# PC shutdown

# ------------- file 2 -------------
import pickle
import itertools

def test(sym, L):
    return (''.join(q) for q in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(sym, repeat=i)for i in range(1, L + 1)))

h = test("1234567890",2)

f = open("test.pickle", "rb")

pickle.load(f)
print(next(h)) # 902???
```

Можно и в одном файле, но сути это особо не изменит. И вообще возможно ли такое сохранить на диске в виде дампа?

Comment: 1- Вся информация необходимая для ответа должна быть в самом вопросе. Минимальный пример кода прямо в вопрос вставьте 2- вот [пример кода, который, используя pickle, обходит генератор в последовательных запусках программы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/500275/23044)

Comment: Таким образом сохраняются все итерации в файл, а если у меня их миллиарды? Просто будет ошибка MemoryError

Comment: пример кода, который я привёл, сохраняет **бесконечное** количество итерацией. (Очевидно что он не требует бесконечной памяти). Количество итераций и потребляемая память не обязаны быть связаны (зависит от алгоритма, который значения генерирует).

Comment: Значит Вы не знаете о чем говорите

Comment: с чем конкретно вы не согласны? С тем что `itertools.cycle({"Мирный житель", "Мафия"})` порождает неограниченное количество элементов. Сколько по вашему итераций будет? Или не согласны с тем что это не требует бесконечной памяти, тогда позапускайте мой пример сколько хотите раз и посмотрите сколько он памяти потребляет (не растёт со временем—`O(1)` памяти).¶ Я не вижу ни словесного описания алгоритма в вашем вопросе ни минимального примера кода, который бы иллюстрировал что вы хотите получить. Код можно легко отформатировать нажав `Ctrl+K` или 4 пробела  добавив в начале.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mQ3QgENj
Если изменить на большую длину символов то памяти явно не хватит. В том примере всего два 2 значения, в моем бесконечно много, в таком плане можно рассматривать. Мне интересно как можно сохранить состояние генератора на том месте где прервался, а не выводить из файла вообще всю итерацию. Т.к. и так можно сначала сгенерировать файл в 200 ГБ и радоваться. Это в примере от 1 до 4 длина перебора, а если надо уже 8, 19, 100, то какой смысл это все сохранять на диск?

Comment: у меня в примере генератор бесконечный. Не путайте, параметры алгоритма и результаты, которые он генерирует¶ То что `TypeError` у вас получается также само по себе ничего не говорит, к примеру `pickle.dumps(i for i in range(10))` также к TypeError ведёт, но `pickle.dumps(iter(range(10**80)))` работает и он НЕ сохраняет `10**80` значений на диск—ещё раз: *параметры алгоритма (состояние) это не его результаты*. Определите, какие параметры нужны, чтобы продолжить выполнение работы вашего алгоритма и сохраняйте их явно или неявно¶ Альтернативно, hibernate машину целиком или запускайте на сервере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! coding: utf-8
import string

CharacterData  = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase# + string.punctuation
#CharacterData += "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя" + "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"

N_dict = {n:c for n,c in zip([n for n in range(len(CharacterData))], [c for c in CharacterData])}
N_dict_r = {j:i for i, j in N_dict.items()}

def converter_in(Int, N = len(N_dict)):
    if Int < N:
        return N_dict[Int]
    Int_ = ""
    while True:
        a, b = divmod(Int, N)
        if a < b:
            Int_ += N_dict[b]
            break
        else:
            Int_ += N_dict[b]
            Int = a
    if N_dict[a] == "0":
        return Int_[::-1]
    else:
        return N_dict[a] + Int_[::-1]

def converter_out(iNT):
    return sum([n * (len(N_dict) ** m) for n, m in zip([N_dict_r[j] for j in iNT[::-1]], [i for i in range(len(iNT))])])

i = -1
while True:
    i += 1
    print(converter_in(i))
```

Вот и другой алгоритм для решения этой задачи. Сохранить значение в файле тут гораздо проще, чем делать дамп. И меня просто реализация интересовала этого, а не использования в каких-то плохих целях. Очень красивое решение для задачи. Если будут ещё интересные решения, то с удовольствием посмотрел, как реализуете.