# Как считать несколько сериализованных объектов из pickle

Tags: python

Как считать в список несколько сериализованных объектов с помощью функции pickle? Пытался считать таким образом:

```
data2 = []
with open("AllOutputMethodsObj.txt", "rb") as f:
    for _ in range(pickle.load(f)):
        data2.append(pickle.load(f))
print (str(data2))
```

Но на выходе получаю ошибку:

```
for _ in range(pickle.load(f)):
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Количество сериализованных объектов мне не известно. На вход подается файл с неизвестным количеством сериализованных объектов.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pickle
objs = dict(a=1, b=2), [3, 4], {5, 6}
pickle.dump(objs, open('test.tt', 'wb'))
for ob in pickle.load(open('test.tt', 'rb')):
    print(ob)
```

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ описание решения проблемы.

Comment: Если скомпилировать подправив ваш код, for ob in pickle.load(open('AllOutputMethodsObj.txt', 'rb')):
    print(ob) то получаю словарь без значении ключей: Название метода
Номер строки
Строка
Номер метода в проекте
Номер метода в файле
Путь к файлу
Конструкция

Answer (score 2):

[`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) всегда содержит ровно один объект. В частности этот объект может быть коллекцией других объектов, например, tuple или [даже итератор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/500275/23044).

```
import pickle

with open("objects.pickle", "rb") as file:
    a, b, c = pickle.load(file)
```

При этом объекты также были сохранены с помощью ровно одного `pickle.dump()` вызова:

```
with open("objects.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump([a, b, c], file)
```

Если вы хотите в разное время объекты сериализовать, [можно `shelve` модуль попробовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html):

```
import shelve

with shelve.open('objects') as db:
    db['a'] = a
    ...
    db['b'] = b
```

Это работает одновременно и на чтение и на запись:

```
with shelve.open('objects') as db:
    a = db['a']  # read
    a += 1       # modify
    db['a'] = a  # write back
```